# Performing aggregation operations in MongoDB to sort data based on specific properties

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I want to sort the data in MongoDB using aggregation operations based on specific attributes. For example, I have hundreds of records like this (under the 'specs' array with spec_id: 1, code: ram, value: 6), and this pattern continues for many phone brands. Additionally, each phone has various spec_id values under the 'specs' array. What I'm looking to achieve is to list the values each spec_id takes under a corresponding 'code' as an array. If a value appears multiple times (e.g., 6 occurs in multiple entries), it should only be listed once, with a 'count' indicating how many times it appears. In the end, I'd like the output to be structured like this within the 'group_by_ram' array: inside the 'buckets' array, there should be objects with 'key' representing the unique values and 'doc_count' indicating how many times each value appears. I attempted to do this using $facet, but since I also used $unwind and $unwind isn't the most reliable option, I'm seeking an alternative solution.

Comment: "_$unwind isn't the most reliable option_" - what does that mean?

Comment: Querying multiple data sets can slow down the system as it has to iterate through each piece of data, so using filters instead would be more logical.

Comment: We'd need sample input documents, the desired output associated with them, and also the aggregations that you have attempted up to this point to really be able to help. Ideally you could share a link to a mongoplayground relevant to your situation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user20042973. "I've solved the problem, and I appreciate your efforts to help. Thank you."